# How to read data from a solidity event in python?

Tags: python, events, solidity

First let me explain code.

Below is the event

`event SubscriptionCreated(uint64 indexed subId, address owner);`

And here is the function where its been emitted

```
function createSubscription() external override returns (uint64 _subId) {
    s_currentSubId++;
    s_subscriptions[s_currentSubId] = Subscription({
        owner: msg.sender,
        balance: 0
    });
    emit SubscriptionCreated(s_currentSubId, msg.sender);
    return s_currentSubId;
}
```

What I am trying to do is to read `subId` from this event, below is the python code.

```
vrf_coordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.deploy(
    config["networks"][network.show_active()]["fee"],
    GAS_PRICE_LINK,
    {"from": account},
)
tx = vrf_coordinator.createSubscription()
tx.wait(1)
SUB_ID = tx.events[0]
print(SUB_ID)
```

first I am deploying the `VRFCoordinatorV2Mock` contract then I am calling the function `createSubscription()` where this event is being emitted, I only know how to access the entire event but dont know how to fetch `subId` from this event.

Last print statement prints the following result

```
OrderedDict([('subId', 2), ('owner', '0x66aB6D9362d4F35596279692F0251Db635165871')])
```

Comment: Just `SUB_ID['subId']`, `collections.OrderedDict` is a (now less useful) `dict` implementation which follows the protocol and implements `__getitem__` in the same way. One thing: please don't name your variable in UPPER_CASE unless it's a scoped constant. It is definitely not a constant here.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch an item from `OrderedDict` (most probably [this one](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)), you can use simply `__getitem__` with square brackets (indexing notation) by key:

```py
vrf_coordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.deploy(
    config["networks"][network.show_active()]["fee"],
    GAS_PRICE_LINK,
    {"from": account},
)
tx = vrf_coordinator.createSubscription()
tx.wait(1)
event = tx.events[0]
print(event)
sub_id = event['subId']
print(sub_id)
```

Comment: Thanks @SUTerliakov for explaining. I found out that there are 2 ways of doing it, I will explain below.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there are 2 ways to get `subId`. First getting it from event like below.

```
subId = tx.events["SubscriptionCreated"]["subId"]
```

And second by using below method

```
subId = tx.return_value
```

It will give you the value returned by `createSubscription()` function.